# Double Loop with R (vector multiplication and n vector creation)

Tags: r, loops, matrix, vector, matrix-multiplication

i'm new user in R, and i'm trying to multiplicate elements of 2 vectors based on a loop and from that create n numbers of new vectors of this dataset

```r
 A = matrix(data= c(1, 2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), nrow= 3, ncol= 3)
B = matrix(data= c(6, 1, 3), nrow= 1, ncol = 3)
C = matrix(data= c(5, 2, 2), nrow = 3, ncol= 1)

b.1 = matrix(data= NA, nrow = 1, ncol =ncol(A))
  for (i in 1:ncol(B))
  b.1[1, i] =((A[,i]%*%C[,ncol(C)]/A[nrow(A),i] ))

c.1 <- matrix(data = NA , nrow  = nrow(C) , 1)
  for (j in 1: nrow(C))  
  c.1[j, 1] = (A[j,]%*%B[nrow(B),]/A[j,ncol(A)])  
  
b.2 <-matrix(data=NA, nrow= 1, ncol= ncol(A))
  for (i in 1:ncol(A))
  b.2[1, i] = ((A[,i]%*%c.1[,ncol(c.1)]/A[nrow(A),i] ))
    
c.2 <- matrix(data= NA, nrow = nrow(C), ncol= 1)
  for (j in 1: nrow(C))
  c.2[j,1] = (A[j,]%*%b.1[nrow(b.1),]/A[j,ncol(A)])
```

Until this part, the code works, but i can't use this double loop, did anyone knows why?
Thanks in advance

```r
##c.x y b.x
for x in 3:10{
  b.[x] <-matrix(data=NA, nrow= 1, ncol= ncol(A))
  for (i in 1:ncol(A))
   b.[x][1, i] = ((A[,i]%*%c.[x-1][,ncol(c.1)]/A[nrow(A),i] ))
c.[x] <- matrix(data= NA, nrow = nrow(C), ncol= 1)
  for (j in 1: nrow(C))
    c.[x][j,1] = (A[j,]%*%b.[x-1][nrow(b.[x-1]),]/A[j,ncol(A)])
```

Comment: `for x in 3:10` is missing the enclosing parens, should it instead be `for (x in 3:10)`?

Comment: @r2evans if i put that, the same message appear "Error: object 'b.' not found"

Comment: Sure. Where do you define `b.`? It's not in this code. BTW, if you are getting errors on your console, why do you think it's a good idea to hide that information from us? If we see `object 'b.' not found`, we are instantly going to ask where you think you are defining it.

Comment: yes, the idea is to create b.3, b.4, b.5, etc, based on the for (x in 3:10). Is kind of based on the local command of stata, 'x´

Comment: oh, that's a good point, sorry, i will add this kind of things in my nexts posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exact problem is a little complicated, so I will simplify so you can see what is not working, and how you can go about making your specific code work.

```
##c.x y b.x
for(x in 3:10){
  b.[x] <-matrix(data=NA, nrow= 1, ncol= ncol(A))
}
# Error: object 'b.' not found
```

Why is `b.` not found? you haven't specified it. In R b.1 and b.2 are not subsets of the same object, they are completely independent objects.

To assign new objects a name in a loop, you can use something like this:

```
for(x in 3:10){
  assign(paste0("b.",x), matrix(data=NA, nrow= 1, ncol= ncol(A)) )
}
```

So now we've created objects named `b.3`, `b.4`, `b.5`, ..., `b.10`, but you still aren't able to simple call `b.[x]` within a loop, because that appears to be an object named `b.` and the xth element in that object, which isn't what you are trying to do.

You have to `get()` the object (now that the objects are created with the last step):

```
for(x in 3:10){
  temp<-get(paste0("b.",x))
  print(temp)
}

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA
```

A silly example adding to columns and then dataframes iteratively in nested for loops:

```
for(x in 3:10){
  assign(paste0("b.",x), matrix(data=NA, nrow= 1, ncol= ncol(A)) )
  temp<-get(paste0("b.",x))
  for(i in 1:ncol(A)){
     temp[1, i]<-paste("whatever you want +",i)
  }
  assign(paste0("b.",x),temp)
}
```

Now let's look at one of the dataframes `b.4` (although with this code each is the same):

```
b.4
     [,1]                    [,2]                      [,3] 
[1,] "whatever you want + 1" "whatever you want + 2"   "whatever you want + 3"
```

So you cannot just add to an object with `.` like you might in other languages.

Comment: Thanks you so much @Dylan_Gomes, your insights were pretty helpful. I have an additional question; how can i point out between the line ´´ temp´´´that i want to use the previus element of b.n. For example, i want to create the vector b.3, but to created it a  need b.2. Again, thank for your helpful insight

Comment: If you want to use the previous object, just use -1 like: `get(paste0("b.",x-1))`. Does this make sense? Or am I misinterpreting your question?

Comment: I think I'm explaining myself badly. What I need is that as I generate a variable b.n, it depends on the element b.n-1, which does not appear in the database currently, but as the loop progresses, it should be created. I understand that get() ends up generating the variables b.n, but I do not know how within a multiplication operation, I can tell the code that it should use the previous element that is automatically generated with the loop,

Comment: `get()` is retrieving the object named within -- you only need it because we are using a `paste` operator, otherwise you could just call the object directly by name (e.g. `b.2`). So if you want to call the previous object, you can use the line above like I suggested. For example you can create a temp object `temp<-get(paste0("b.",x-1))` and then work with this "previous" element in the next loop.

Comment: Thank you so much @Dylan_Gomes, i have solved my problem, you just have to point out temp (with the lag) in the operation :D